# Clicking add comment makes the comments move under the text on the right

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I noticed that every time I click on "add comment", both my own comment and the comments above get expanded horizontally a bit, so they move partly under the text on the right. Refreshing the page clears the problem, and all comments are displayed correctly again, including my own comment.

I use Firefox on Windows Vista.

EDIT :

I only experience the problem at home, not at work apparently. At home it's Windows Vista. I'll take a screenshot tonight.

EDIT : screenshot :
[image]

Comment: Screenshot? I run that setup at work and I haven't noticed anything abnormal.

Comment: Screenshot added

Comment: I can't reproduce this in Firefox..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce this in firefox. I suspect you're using font size overrides instead of full page zoom. See:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-two-types-of-browser-zoom.html

Comment: Duuh! *smash forehead* Indeed, I use a bigger font size at home. Gonna change that, thx for the pointer.

Comment: @JeffAtwood Got the same bug, but on Chrome, posted screenshot as an answer here. Could you please revisit this?

Comment: The "Minimum font size" setting in both Opera and Chrome also trigger this behaviour. Haven't tested any other browsers. It happened to me if I set the value higher than 13. Been driving me mad for ages and finally glad to discover the source.